# How do you unbind an event?

Tags: jquery, events

I have this:

```
$(document).on('click','[name=Save]',ConjunctionJunction)
function ConjunctionJunction() {
   $(this).unbind()
   $(this).unbind('click')
   $(document).unbind('click','[name=Save]')
}
```

Q: How do I unbind it? Oh wait: I could say '.one()'! But still though, I'd like to know how to unbind an event.

Comment: But that just makes too much sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.off()` to unbind an event that was bound using `.on()`.

[jQuery docs for .off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

In your example, use:

```
$(document).off('click','[name=Save]',ConjunctionJunction);
```

Comment: It's not `$(document).off()`, just `off()`. `document` just happens to be the element OP bound the event on.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but in your case $(this) refers to the `window`, not to the `document`. So you could use any of these:

```
$(document).unbind();
$(document).unbind('click');
$(document).unbind('click', '[name=Save]');
```